# Rsync limit transfer speed not working

Tags: rsync

i'm trying to limit the bandwidth Rsync is using by specifying the --bwlimit option, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know if i'm doing something wrong... :

The maximum possible upload speed = 10mbit/sec. I'd like to limit rsync to about 50% :

Rsync command =

```
[~] # rsync --version
rsync  version 3.0.7  protocol version 30

[~] # rsync -a --verbose --partial --bwlimit=500 -e 'ssh -p 2200 -i /share/ssh/id_dsa' admin@10.0.3.10:/share/MD0_DATA/ /share/LocalData
```

Result =

[image: Traffic]

==============================================================================

Solution as provided below:

```
[~] # ipkg install trickle
Installing trickle (1.06-3) to root...
Downloading http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/ts509/cross/unstable/trickle_1.06-3_i686.ipk
Installing libevent (2.0.16-1) to root...
Downloading http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/ts509/cross/unstable/libevent_2.0.16-1_i686.ipk
Configuring libevent
Configuring trickle
Successfully terminated. 
[~] # trickle -d 500 rsync -a --verbose --partial -e 'ssh -p 2200 -i /share/ssh/id_dsa' admin@10.0.3.10:/share/MD0_DATA/ /share/LocalData
trickle: Could not reach trickled, working independently: No such file or directory
receiving incremental file list
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

--bwlimit=KBytes/s applies a moving average to throttle the resulting throughput,
so you'll only notice it for a transfer which is considerably larger than your available bandwidth.

from the [man](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2007/rsync-basics.html) pages,

> blocks of data are sent, then if rsync determines the transfer was too fast, it will wait before sending the next data block. The result is an average transfer rate equaling the specified limit.)

Take a look into [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle) which seems to take on this concept with a more refined algorithm.

Comment: For anyone too lazy to read the MAN page, the KBPS refers to KiloBYTES per second, not KiloBITS per second. Thanks for the tip, I always refer to your answer by the way :)

Comment: 10 mbps is approximately equal to 1.2 MB/sec, so that's still far above 500 KB/sec.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I really like `cstream` http://www.cons.org/cracauer/cstream.html.

> cstream is a general-purpose stream-handling tool like UNIX dd, usually used in commandline-constructed pipes

It might be possible to use it with rsync, no experience with that. Here is an example how to use it with `tar`.

http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2543/throttle-bandwidth-with-cstream

**TL;DR**

```
tar -cj /backup | cstream -t 777k | ssh host 'tar -xj -C /backup'
```

Answer (score 0):

The limit option (-l) seems to work fine in `scp`, which uses nearly the same syntax as rsync, and could be used as an alternative.

`scp -l 200 hugefile.tgz example.org:bigstuff/`

Example taken from: http://betabug.ch/blogs/ch-athens/934