# How to limit packets per second in rsync?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

Recently, my host's firewall started to block every IP that goes beyond 9000 packets per second. I have set up a cron job in my Ubuntu server which will use rsync to backup and push it to a remote server. Recently, while running this backup it started to exceed the limit so my server got blocked. So my question is, how to limit rsync to 9000 packets per second?

PS : I use Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rsync limit transfer speed not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064316/rsync-limit-transfer-speed-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's time to vote with your money and take your business elsewhere (and make sure they know *why*). In the meantime ...

I don't think it's possible to know how many packets a particular transmission will have: it depends how much the data gets subdivided, and that depends on many factors including random chance, I think.

Rsync does provide a bandwidth limiting feature, and I suggest you try that and see how you get on:

For example, this will limit rsync to 500 KByte/sec, which is very approximately 5Mbits/s:

```
rsync --bwlimit=500  ......
```

(Yes, I know there are 8 bits in a byte, but that doesn't take network overhead into account.)

You could start by limiting it to half your supposed maximum bandwidth. If that works then you could go up to three quarters. If that doesn't work then try half way between the two, and so on until you find the maximum reliable number.

Answer (score 0):

Like ams has pointed out,
you can only limit the transfered bandwidth, not the packets count,

--bwlimit=KBPS applies a moving average to throttle the resulting throughput,
so you'll only notice it for a transfer which is considerably larger than your available bandwidth.

from the [man](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2007/rsync-basics.html) pages,

> blocks of data are sent, then if rsync determines the transfer was too fast, it will wait before sending the next data block. The result is an average transfer rate equaling the specified limit.)

Take a look into [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle) which seems to take on this concept with a more refined algorithm.